# sqlite - query to fill consecutive value when missing

Tags: sql, sqlite

i'm writing a query that return me missing consecutive values in the source table on the field "RR" (the other fields shold be obviously null)
so i wrote a cte table that generate a sequence from 1 to 10 and it works

```
WITH generate_sequence(rr) AS(SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT rr+1 FROM generate_sequence LIMIT 10)
SELECT * FROM generate_sequence
```

than i put this cte in left join with my table

```
SELECT * FROM generate_sequence LEFT JOIN StoricoSistemiResults ON generate_sequence.rr = StoricoSistemiResults.rr
ORDER BY Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto, NumeriGiocati, RR
```

but this query doesn't give me the missing row

this is the source table

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "StoricoSistemiResults" (
    "Id"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "SessionId" TEXT NOT NULL,
    "Title" TEXT,
    "NomeSistema"   TEXT,
    "TipoSistema"   TEXT,
    "Giocata"   INTEGER,
    "DataEstrazioneConfronto"   TEXT,
    "NumeroEstrazioneConfronto" INTEGER,
    "RR"    INTEGER,
    "NumeriGiocati" INTEGER,
    "MatchCount"    INTEGER,
    "MatchNumeri"   TEXT,
    "Schedina"  TEXT,
    "Vincita"   INTEGER,
    "VincitaImporto"    INTEGER,
    "ConfrontoMatchCount"   INTEGER,
    "ConfrontoMatchNumeri"  TEXT,
    "ConfrontoSchedina" TEXT,
    "ConfrontoVincita"  INTEGER,
    "ConfrontoVincitaImporto"   INTEGER,
    "Annotazioni"   TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY("Id" AUTOINCREMENT)
);
INSERT INTO "StoricoSistemiResults" ("Id","SessionId","Title","NomeSistema","TipoSistema","Giocata","DataEstrazioneConfronto","NumeroEstrazioneConfronto","RR","NumeriGiocati","MatchCount","MatchNumeri","Schedina","Vincita","VincitaImporto","ConfrontoMatchCount","ConfrontoMatchNumeri","ConfrontoSchedina","ConfrontoVincita","ConfrontoVincitaImporto","Annotazioni") VALUES 
 (1295,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',27,4,3,1,'43','22.87.43',0,0,1,'55','30.55.61',0,0,''),
 (1296,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',27,3,3,0,'','35.53.2',0,0,1,'29','10.29.79',0,0,''),
 (1297,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',27,2,3,0,'','72.65.48',0,0,1,'20','20.33.88',0,0,''),
 (1298,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',27,1,3,2,'40.41','40.59.41',1,2,0,'','42.45.71',0,0,''),
 (1299,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',27,0,3,0,'','7.74.66',0,0,0,'','8.38.66',0,0,''),
 (1300,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',27,4,6,3,'28.43.67','22.28.67.50.43.64',1,2,4,'24.29.40.85','24.26.29.36.40.85',1,10,''),
 (1301,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',27,3,6,2,'55.84','84.10.55.2.69.53',0,0,1,'85','5.11.16.65.77.85',0,0,''),
 (1302,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',27,2,6,1,'20','3.20.78.8.72.57',0,0,2,'43.85','3.8.35.43.48.85',0,0,''),
 (1303,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',27,1,6,1,'40','76.40.9.27.70.59',0,0,1,'46','7.26.42.46.75.81',0,0,''),
 (1304,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',27,0,6,3,'23.34.46','34.30.68.23.46.45',1,2,0,'','26.33.54.66.78.86',0,0,''),
 (1305,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',28,5,3,2,'4.71','71.4.87',1,2,0,'','5.11.18',0,0,''),
 (1306,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',28,3,3,0,'','38.57.48',0,0,1,'7','7.26.48',0,0,''),
 (1307,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',28,2,3,1,'27','70.61.27',0,0,2,'6.46','6.46.69',1,2,''),
 (1308,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',28,1,3,1,'12','73.44.12',0,0,0,'','28.50.75',0,0,''),
 (1309,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',28,0,3,1,'1','34.84.1',0,0,2,'31.71','31.71.80',1,2,''),
 (1310,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',28,5,6,2,'4.71','64.87.50.4.22.71',0,0,1,'25','13.25.32.48.66.75',0,0,''),
 (1311,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',28,3,6,0,'','57.79.72.38.78.65',0,0,0,'','28.35.44.51.61.65',0,0,''),
 (1312,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',28,2,6,1,'25','61.32.13.70.25.76',0,0,1,'6','6.38.60.65.66.85',0,0,''),
 (1313,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',28,1,6,2,'7.12','44.42.73.7.12.63',0,0,1,'74','9.16.30.53.61.74',0,0,''),
 (1314,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',28,0,6,3,'20.46.56','20.56.46.29.28.55',1,2,2,'27.81','5.22.27.40.81.83',0,0,''),
 (1315,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',29,4,3,1,'65','48.8.65',0,0,2,'1.69','1.11.69',1,2,''),
 (1316,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',29,3,3,0,'','32.16.76',0,0,0,'','26.33.70',0,0,''),
 (1317,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',29,2,3,2,'68.73','68.73.63',1,2,1,'68','54.57.68',0,0,''),
 (1318,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',29,1,3,1,'29','40.29.34',0,0,0,'','17.26.78',0,0,''),
 (1319,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',29,0,3,1,'10','45.10.47',0,0,1,'88','26.71.88',0,0,''),
 (1320,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',29,4,6,1,'65','3.78.72.65.79.38',0,0,1,'88','6.16.33.62.79.88',0,0,''),
 (1321,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',29,3,6,0,'','32.16.13.70.59.61',0,0,1,'5','2.5.19.33.47.55',0,0,''),
 (1322,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',29,2,6,1,'73','62.63.30.73.66.42',0,0,0,'','23.27.30.47.56.76',0,0,''),
 (1323,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',29,1,6,1,'29','52.55.21.40.29.34',0,0,1,'60','35.36.45.58.60.66',0,0,''),
 (1324,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',29,0,6,1,'10','10.36.71.6.47.27',0,0,3,'68.75.84','26.59.62.68.75.84',1,2,''),
 (1325,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,5,3,0,'','57.78.79',0,0,1,'33','33.67.79',0,0,''),
 (1326,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,4,3,0,'','61.70.32',0,0,0,'','4.78.82',0,0,''),
 (1327,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,3,3,0,'','30.44.66',0,0,0,'','18.34.36',0,0,''),
 (1328,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,2,3,2,'21.40','40.21.28',1,2,1,'5','5.28.38',0,0,''),
 (1329,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,1,3,1,'56','56.46.19',0,0,0,'','37.46.78',0,0,''),
 (1330,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,0,3,1,'10','29.60.10',0,0,1,'51','18.27.51',0,0,''),
 (1331,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,5,6,0,'','38.3.48.8.78.57',0,0,0,'','3.23.34.65.86.87',0,0,''),
 (1332,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,4,6,1,'16','61.32.16.59.70.76',0,0,2,'10.51','10.14.42.50.51.78',0,0,''),
 (1333,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,3,6,0,'','30.62.63.44.66.42',0,0,0,'','14.39.45.55.67.86',0,0,''),
 (1334,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,2,6,3,'21.40.51','51.40.21.67.28.24',1,2,2,'10.51','4.10.34.51.54.80',0,0,''),
 (1335,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,1,6,1,'56','6.46.56.25.27.43',0,0,1,'85','43.49.54.63.66.85',0,0,''),
 (1336,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',30,0,6,4,'9.10.69.75','37.9.69.10.75.73',1,10,2,'9.71','9.32.38.42.67.71',0,0,''),
 (1337,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,6,3,2,'72.78','48.78.72',1,2,0,'','8.23.47',0,0,''),
 (1338,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,5,3,1,'76','13.76.70',0,0,1,'45','36.45.48',0,0,''),
 (1339,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,4,3,0,'','44.62.66',0,0,0,'','3.52.87',0,0,''),
 (1340,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,3,3,1,'55','55.23.28',0,0,0,'','15.67.85',0,0,''),
 (1341,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,2,3,1,'45','45.19.7',0,0,0,'','18.57.59',0,0,''),
 (1342,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,1,3,0,'','65.87.74',0,0,0,'','5.10.18',0,0,''),
 (1343,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,0,3,1,'64','64.9.20',0,0,0,'','23.31.71',0,0,''),
 (1344,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,6,6,2,'72.78','8.48.3.78.79.72',0,0,1,'56','5.31.56.71.74.85',0,0,''),
 (1345,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,5,6,2,'61.76','70.59.13.61.32.76',0,0,1,'60','7.21.60.65.68.83',0,0,''),
 (1346,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,4,6,0,'','66.30.44.62.63.42',0,0,0,'','32.38.44.58.75.84',0,0,''),
 (1347,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,3,6,3,'24.34.55','52.23.34.24.67.55',1,2,3,'55.64.77','27.32.55.59.64.77',1,2,''),
 (1348,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,2,6,1,'45','19.6.4.45.27.47',0,0,1,'78','4.14.15.38.52.78',0,0,''),
 (1349,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,1,6,1,'60','60.37.74.87.49.86',0,0,1,'22','4.22.42.62.80.84',0,0,''),
 (1350,'e9f0d29e-8354-4969-804a-1e521813b43e','prova ordinamento NumeriGiocati, RR, Date(DataEstrazioneConfronto), NumeroEstrazioneConfronto','Pick from imminente caldo','Mono',1,'2023-11-10',31,0,6,0,'','41.71.40.9.31.5',0,0,2,'56.72','6.23.44.56.63.72',0,0,'');

 COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need also `NumeroEstrazioneConfronto`, `NumeriGiocati` to find missing `RR` ?

```
SELECT NumeroEstrazioneConfronto, NumeriGiocati, rr
FROM StoricoSistemiResults
```

If yes, to have all possible values :

```
WITH all_rr(rr) AS(
    values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)
), all_numero AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT NumeroEstrazioneConfronto, NumeriGiocati
    FROM StoricoSistemiResults
)
SELECT *
FROM all_numero
CROSS JOIN all_rr;
```

And finally :

```
WITH all_rr(rr) AS(
    values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10)
), all_numero AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT NumeroEstrazioneConfronto, NumeriGiocati
    FROM StoricoSistemiResults
), all_numero_rr AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM all_numero
    CROSS JOIN all_rr
)
SELECT *
FROM all_numero_rr a    
LEFT JOIN StoricoSistemiResults s
    ON a.NumeroEstrazioneConfronto = s.NumeroEstrazioneConfronto
    AND a.NumeriGiocati = s.NumeriGiocati
    AND a.rr = s.rr
```

NULLs are missing rows